# Generation of Optional<?> getters for non-mandatory xsd attributes

Tags: java, xsd, xjc

Consider the following XML Schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema
    targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema1.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema1.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:complexType name="Appointment">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="startTimestamp" type="xs:dateTime" />
                    <xs:element name="endTimestamp" type="xs:dateTime" />
                    <xs:element name="subject" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="tag" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="category" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="note" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

when using xjc to generate the code I get getters and setters for the respective attributes.

Several of this attributes are, however, optional, as minOccurs denotes. Does there exist any means to generate getters and setters for optional attributes using [Java 8 Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) - such that for example

```
public Optional<String> getSubject()
```

instead of

```
public String getSubject()
```